# functional keyword in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I found this piece of code:

```
let functional ((fi: mval store -> mval store)) =
function sigma ->
let g = sem e r sigma in
if typecheck("bool",g) then
(if g = Bool(true) then fi(semcl cl r sigma) else sigma)
else failwith ("nonboolean guard")
```

But I did not understand what the functional keyword means, I tried to look for it in the docs but I did not found it.

Comment: I think it might be an arbitrary identifier, not a keyword, which would explain it's absence from docs

Answer (score 4):

It's not a keyword, it's the name of the function being defined.

Comment: Needless to say, this is a terrible function name.